# Google Maps API V3 - Japanese String Comparison and Marker Image

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a simple map application using Google Maps API V3 for JavaScript. I want to show a certain marker image for each location based on IF condition. Here is some code:

```
var myIcon, greenPinIcon, bluePinIcon;
greenPinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/pin_green.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(50,50));
bluePinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/pin_blue.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(50,50));

for(i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
{
  if (locations[i][5] == "保守新政の会")
     {
           myIcon = greenPinIcon;
     }
  else
     {
           myIcon = bluePinIcon;
     }

        marker = new MarkerWithLabel(
            {
                position: position,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                raiseOnDrag: false,
                title: locations[i][2],
                labelContent: locations[i][2],
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
                icon: myIcon
            }
        );

}
```

"locations" is a multi-dimensional array containing values: Latitude, Longitude, Name, Phone, Address, Group. Here are a few rows as a sample.

```
35.866446,139.803246,伊藤治,985-4826,越谷市蒲生三丁目7番7号,自由民主党/市民クラブ
35.877096,139.770734,野口佳司,964-9527,越谷市七左町七丁目175番地,自由民主党/市民クラブ
35.869426,139.780875,樫村紀元,987-1985,越谷市七左町一丁目332番地9,保守新政の会
```

I cannot see the desired result and all markers are being displayed with "bluePinIcon" as the marker icon. I am not sure whether it is Japanese string or something else which is causing the problem. I have included `<meta charset="utf-8" />` as well to support unicode characters.

I am new to JavaScript and Google Maps API. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If all markers are being displayed as the greenPinIcon, I'd assume your Japanese string is being read ok.  I'd be curious to know your results if you change that IF statement to something like `if (i % 2)` what do you get?

Comment: Also the MarkerImage class has been deprecated in favour of [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

Comment: if (i % 2) shows markers with both icons. It means that IF condition is failing each time but why?

Comment: no that's fine, it should show half the markers with green and half with blue. I was trying to see if there was a problem with the MarkerWithLabel itself.

Comment: Can you post a sample few rows of the locations array to your question?

Comment: Oh, I see you've updated the question to indicate all markers are Blue, not Green.  In that case yes, it's probably due to the Japanese characters. It would still be useful to see the locations array

Comment: No reason for this not to work. Are you sure about `locations[i][5]`? Array position starts at 0.

Comment: the `locations`...where do they come from(external script, ajax)?

Comment: @duncan...I have included sample rows of locations array which contains Japanese characters.

Comment: @Dr.Molle...This array is coming from a text file. I am using "locations" data in InfoWindow as well and everything displays correctly.

Comment: Your sample doesn't contain any rows where the 6th array element is `"日本語"`.  So given that sample I'd only expect to see the Blue icon

Comment: duncan's comment is right. The data doesn't have "日本語" in the 6th array element.  "日本語" means just "Japanese" in Japanese.

Comment: @duncan...It was just a sample in order to show you how Japanese characters are being placed in array. The string "日本語" was in array list when I checked that code. I have tried various Japanese strings but to no avail. Anyway, I have updated the code and I am getting the same result (Blue Icon).

Comment: @naota...<<< 日本語 means just "Japanese" in Japanese >>> Thank you for the information. Please refer to my previous comment about "日本語" string.

Comment: can you do `console.log(locations[i][5]);` in the `else` clause to find out what your JS thinks it is?